# should I include offer letter from a different institution in my application for a faculty position

Tags: application, faculty-application, application-cover-letter

I have a offer letter from a very well-known group in my field for a postdoc position. The proposed starting date would be early next year.
However, I am currently also applying for a faculty (assistant professor) position at a different institution.

Should I mention this offer in my application for the faculty position (on cv or cover letter) and/or include the official offer letter?

*update:*

there is another sublety for one application. One faculty position I consider requires experience abroad (i.e. not in the same country) of at least 1 year. I only have 6 months but the postdoc offer would be abroad giving me the 1 year total if I take it before starting the faculty position. Should I then mention the offer?

my field is health and medical sciences

Comment: Why? I don't know academia much so I'm curious about what you could gain from this. I would do something like that to negotiate a better salary in industry, but I thought that faculty had fixed salaries, at least at the beginning.

Comment: @Elzo I would hope that having an offer letter from this very well known group would increase my chances for the faculty position. Everybody knows this group in my field.

Comment: But didn't this group see the same CV you are sending to this different institution? That the group accepted you just tells them "these very smart people liked the attached CV so you should too". Couldn't it even offend them?

Comment: @Elzo this is exactly the question

Comment: About update: so, does the job at the Different Institution start in over 6 months from now, and you expect to be done with the postdoc stuff at the Well-Known Group before that? Otherwise, it's hard to see how it's relevant.

Comment: Definitely not. That is part of a commercial negotiation between you and a third party. It is nobody else's business whatsoever.

Comment: Are you going to do the postdoc position? You could always just accept it, and then you're not listing an offer but an actual position (one that you will hold between now and your start date in any other position that you're applying for). Of course, that limits you to definitely doing the postdoc, since if you show up having not done it there could be questions...

Answer (score 28):

I think that it would be unwise to include a copy of an offer in another application.

But whether you inform them of the existence of an offer is a bit more subtle. I doubt that anyone will rush to hire you just because you have another offer. They will evaluate you on other things as usual. So, at best, mentioning the offer initially gets you nothing.

However, later in the process if you need a decision and they are delaying making it, you can let them know that you have a deadline. Whether that helps or hurts is also subtle. Whether it is wise, or not depends on the nature of any relationship you have been able to build with them. In the absence of any relationship, it might hurt more than help. It is easy to just cross you off the list unless they are very interested and have few other interesting applicants.

Answer (score 19):

To be blunt and clear, if anyone had done this on any of the previous hiring committees I have been on, we would have rejected them instantly. They would not have even been long-listed, let alone short listed. Having another job offer is not a reason for anyone to hire you. Indeed, it indicated a number of negative things:

1. You are the sort of person who goes all the way through the process of getting one job but still fishes around for something "better": read, you waste everyone's time
2. If they do want you, you are likely to try to pull off some sort of bidding  war for you, increasing your package etc. That's annoying to everyone.
3. You are implying that the research group you have a PostDoc offer from is somehow better than the place you are looking for a Faculty Position from. Like some temporary position is as good as a tenure track one. Ouch!
4. You are lacking in subtlety, diplomacy, and general workplace etiquette.

Basically, don't do this. It is a very bad idea.

Comment: thanks for this clear answer. I updated my question, what would be the right thing to do here?

Comment: This actually happened during my first hiring committee experience: An otherwise impressive application has a competing job offer attached to the cover letter. All the senior people in the committee completely ignored the application. When I voiced my support for this candidate, I was given the "are you stupid look".

Comment: This is a rather extreme answer. Particularly item 1, which sounds very unreasonable. Really, it is wrong to simultaneously apply to multiple positions and not jump on the first offer that comes along (especially for a postdoc when you were hoping for an assistant professorship) but hope to get additional offers and do whatever you need to to maximize your chances? That’s news to me and everyone I know (but maybe we’re all “that sort of people” you were referring to). What am I missing here, GrotesqueSI?

Comment: @ssquidd Please say that person asked for feedback on their application materials...

Comment: (To be clear, I agree that including the other offer letter is a bad idea. Mentioning the offer itself may or may not be a good idea, depending on many specific details as discussed in Buffy’s answer. But the absolutist tone of this answer does not leave a good impression, especially item 1 as I said.)

Comment: @DanRomik The main issue is the total lack of diplomacy. It comes off as completely disrespecting the institution that offered the post doc: an institution that went through the whole search and hiring process, who disappointed other candidates, and who gave the poster a sincere offer. Yes, one should take something better if it comes along, but to so overtly use this other offer as a springboard is crass and a fantastic way to burn bridges.

Comment: @DanRomik apologies if you felt the tone was harsh. I'm basically giving the senior faculty "are you stupid look" that ssquidd mentioned in their comment, only in typed form.

Comment: You sound like a very sensible person and I generally like your answers a lot. This one seems off the mark. Ruling out candidates for committing a minor social faux pas (even assuming that the action we’re discussing is such a thing; if done correctly it doesn’t have to be) doesn’t sound wise or fair to me, nor does jumping to conclusions about someone’s character based on such tiny amounts of evidence.

Comment: @DanRomik People are generally on their *best* behaviour when applying for a job. If this is the OP's "best behaviour", it's hardly "jumping to conclusions" to consider how they might behave in "normal" situations, and betting with the odds is usually a good strategy. Recruitment isn't about looking for the *ideal* candidate (because with limited information you have no way to achieve that). It's about making the lowest-risk decision that someone is  *good enough*.

Comment: Ehhh, I totally believe you someones application like this would get binned, but getting an offer letter isn't "going all the way through getting a job" and the OP is doing nothing wrong by looking for something better

Comment: I agree with @DanRomik, this attitude seems unreasonable (although that doesn't make the answer any less valuable, as it shows that hiring committees may be unreasonable in this way). 1: No, it just shows the person is not willing to give up on the chance of a permanent job to take a temporary one, which is normal. 2: I don't think there is any reason to think this - unless you're paying less for your faculty position than other institutions are for their postdoc positions, the other offer isn't a negotiating tool.

Comment: 3: On the contrary, it says the candidate is not applying merely because they have no other options, but because they genuinely want this position. 4: If by "subtlety and diplomacy" you mean "being less open", I'm not sure that's a good thing.

Comment: I agree about the "not including" part, I disagree about "not letting know" in general. E.g., clearly the candidate thinks the tenure track is better than the postdoc, otherwise they'd not apply now. But I agree in this case --- I just don't see what the candidate wins from letting it be known, "the others think I'm good enough for a postdoc, so you have to agree on my lecturer skills"? If anything, the committee concluded "This one is safe, won't drop out of academia, no need to give the edge on that ground" and take another (e.g., minority/underrepresented) candidate.

Comment: @DanRomik Again, fair if you think I am being unreasonable, but think of me as representative of a likely make up of the committee. Sure it may be unreasonable for the reasons you say for the committee to think my 1, 2, and 3, but they are very likely to think it.

Answer (score -3):

You do not show a letter addressed to you personally to other people without the sender`s (explicit or implicit) consent. 
Never, if you have any doubt, unless you get a formal court order to do so.